# Prevent optional dependencies during pm2 install (npm --no-optional)

Tags: npm, pm2

Is there a way to pass the `--no-optional` parameter through to `npm` when using `pm2 install`?

In an environment with restricted outgoing traffic `pm2 install pm2-fluentd` hangs for a while until it times out while attempting to install the optional `pm2` dependency:

`"gkt": "https://tgz.pm2.io/gkt-1.0.0.tgz"`

In the same environment `npm install --no-optional pm2-fluentd` succeeds quickly, however running this prior to `pm2 install` does not avoid waiting for the timeout. Being able to pass `--no-optional` would allow me to install modules in seconds rather than 5 minutes. Is there a way to accomplish this, or will PM2 require an enhancement?

Answer (score 1):

This is documented in multiple closed issues at the PM2 GitHub, including [#3444](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/3444) where the maintainer explains the web URL is intentionally used to gather download metrics, and there is no plan to remove it.

A potential workaround is described in [#2507](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2507). Here's a version modified for the pm2-fluentd plugin:

```
git clone https://github.com/bunnyyiu/pm2-fluentd.git && cd pm2-fluentd && pm2 install .
```

It's probably wise to fork the git repo, and use your own copy, if you need this for production use.